# Execute chef resource multiple times with variables

Tags: chef, chef-solo

Consider the following code:

```
node["cloudwatch"]["alarms"].each do |metric,keys|
  script_name = "/root/.cloudwatch/create_cloudwatch_alarm-#{metric}.sh"
  template script_name do
    source  "cloudwatch/create_cloudwatch_EC2_alarm.sh.erb"
    owner   "root"
    group   "root"
    mode    "0655"
    variables(
      :metric => metric,
      :description => keys["description"],
      :statistic => keys["statistic"],
      :comparison => keys["comparison"],
      :threshold => keys["threshold"],
      :evalperiods => keys["evalperiods"],
      :period => keys["period"]
    )   
    notifies :run, "bash[populate-create_alarms]", :immediately
  end 
  bash "populate-create_alarms" do
    user "root"
    cwd "/root/.cloudwatch/"
    code <<-EOH
      echo #{script_name} >> ./create_alarms.sh
      EOH
    action :nothing
  end 
end
```

This runs fine, but in the log I get the following warnings several times:

```
WARN: Cloning resource attributes for bash[populate-create_alarms] from prior resource (CHEF-3694)
WARN: Previous bash[populate-create_alarms]: /var/chef-solo/cookbooks/soapp/recipes/cloudwatch.rb:220:in `block in from_file'
WARN: Current  bash[populate-create_alarms]: /var/chef-solo/cookbooks/soapp/recipes/cloudwatch.rb:220:in `block in from_file'
```

I understand why I'm getting the warnings, but I don't know how to avoid them. Clearly `"populate-create_alarms"` should not be inside the `node["cloudwatch"]["alarms"].each` block, but I don't know how to pass `#{script_name}` to `"populate-create_alarms"`. Anyone show me the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Make the `bash` resource name unique, by e.g. the following code:

```
 bash "populate-create_alarms-#{metric}" do
   ..
 end
```